# Printing via ASP.NET Core-Web-Api hosted as Windows Service

Tags: printing, swagger, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to **ASP.NET Core-Web-Api**, maybe you have some tips for me. I use **ASP.NET Core 7.0**. I host my publication as a **Windows service**. As basis I use the demo application of the [weather forecast from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). I have extended this so that I can list all local Windows printers and print a simple sting via another interface.

When I build my ASP.NET Core-Web-Api via Visual Studio I can choose to host it with "**https**" or "**IIS Express**" in debug or release mode. Via Swagger I can use all my functions even a print works.

[image]

Now I have my application hosted as a **Windows service**, also the application is accessible via **Swagger**. I can list my printers and also get data about my wather forecast. But I can not create a print anymore?

- Endless loop when called but with status code 200 OK. There is also no job to be found in my printer queue.
- **Does my hosting via Visual Studio behave differently than my hosting in the Windows service?**
- My Windows-service is started via a local admin account, my printer is also usable for everyone.

[image]

I use the following packages

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I create my document with PageDocument, works fine from Visual Studio but not from Windows-service.

```
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();            
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;            
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
    pd.Print();
```

For **System.Printing** and **System.Drawing.Printing** I have also seen the hints. Therefore I assume it is because of my hosting as Windows service.

> Classes within the System.Printing namespace are not supported for use
> within a Windows service or ASP.NET application or service. Attempting
> to use these classes from within one of these application types may
> produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance
> and run-time exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be the permission issue. Please find the printer service, and change the log on user.

You can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to verify it.

**Related Link**

[Problem with Windows Service and network printers](https://serverfault.com/questions/65476/problem-with-windows-service-and-network-printers)